# Exploring the constant $-\int_0^1\log\left(1-H_x\right)\log\left(1+H_{2x}\right)\,dx$, where $H_y$ are harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, harmonic-numbers

This morning I try to create interesting integrals involving harmonic numbers. See this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). And look at, also if you need it, the definition of the Harmonic number $H_x$ using the digamma function from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html).

After I've asked to Wolfram Alpha online calculator this code

`int -log(1-Harmonic(x))log(1+Harmonic(2x))dx, from x=0 to 1`

I wondered this

> **Question.** Can you justify a very good approximation of this  $$\text{constant}=-\int_0^1\log\left(1-H_x\right)\log\left(1+H_{2x}\right)\,dx\tag{1}$$ using numerical analysis? Or well, can you provide me the expression of previous constant written as a series with a good rate of convergence? **Many thanks.**

You can to choose some of the two previous approaches. But if 
a different approach (yours) gets a very good approximation/information of the constant defined in $(1)$, feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: I added previous tags because these are good, but this problem is also about **(integration)**. Many thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:asymptotics]? It does not seem to be relevant.

Comment: Many thanks, following your experience now I remove this tag. And thanks for your attention and help @AntonioVargas

Comment: I made a Taylor expansion of the integrand around $x=\frac 12$ up to fourth order ;  it is just ugly (a bunch of polygamma functions) but, for sure, you can integrate termwise. The numerical value so obtained is $-0.847997$ to be compared to $-0.987235$ obtained by numerical integration.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort and contribution @ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, the expansion around $x=\frac 12$ is more than ugly. Moroever, the convergence does not look to ve very fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{result} \\
 2 & 0.847997 \\
 4 & 0.901222 \\
 6 & 0.925063 \\
 8 & 0.938477 \\
 10 &0.947086
\end{array}
\right)$$

A quick and dirty nonlinear regression $$y=\frac{0.619974+0.809459\, n}{1+0.820115\, n}$$ leads to an asymptotic value of $0.987006$.

Comment: Any case, many thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @user243301. You are very welcome ! My computer gave up trying $n=20$. This problem is awful (as I did approach it). May I ask where did you find it ?

Comment: Was a creation when I was inspired in PROBLEMA 124 La Gaceta de la RSME Vol. 13, nº 1, page 82 by Pablo Refolio (2010), with the purpose to write an integral about harmonic numbers $H_x$ or $H_{\lambda x}$. Look at from the web or [La Gaceta de la Real Sociedad Matemática Española](http://gaceta.rsme.es/), and choose the links > **english**, >All issues, >Volume 13 (2010), >Issue 1 and finally **Soluciones a los problemas 121 al 124 y 126**.

Comment: On the other hand this journal has very nice articles, but in spanish language, for example is it interesting the following article >english, >Sections, > **The Column of Computational Mathematics**, and in page 3, choose  *¿Podemos fiarnos de los cálculos efectuados con ordenador?* by Óscar Ciaurri and  Juan Luis Varona  (published in La Gaceta de la RSME, volume 9, issue 2 (2006)).